# How would I obtain the first sentence after a section title?

Tags: r

I had a small problem.

I have text that looks like:

```
A.1    skldjlsfslfjd skdlsdj sljfdkjd
Hello my name is John. Blah blah blah.
A.2    skldljsdlkd dkdkd adjklsdk.
Hello my last name is Doe. akdjkld slkdlk ldksdl
```

I would like my output to look like:

```
A.1    skldjlsfslfjd skdlsdj sljfdkjd 
Hello my name is John.
A.2    skldljsdlkd dkdkd adjklsdk
Hello my last name is Doe.
```

I already have:

```
A.1    skldjlsfslfjd skdlsdj sljfdkjd

A.2    skldljsdlkd dkdkd adjklsdk
```

I'm just having trouble getting the next sentence.

Comment: Is it a scalar or vector character? Are there new line characters? Can you `dput()` the example?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far, including an explicit way of loading the source text?  What parts are constant  -just `Hello my name is`?  Will the names ever contain spaces or non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: It is a vector character

Comment: Hi, the code I used so far is grep("(^[A-Z]\\.\\d+)", text, value=TRUE)

Comment: "Hello my name" is not necessarily constant. I just chose it as a random sentence and yes the name can have any non-alphanumeric character and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't have much context outside of the example.

I'm going to take a guess that we know a title is a title because it has A.x (A.1, A.2, etc). You can modify that as necessary for A-Z or whatever the actual format is in your real world example.

For the other sentences it looks like you want everything up to the first ".". I combine the logic for both parts into 1 line with `ifelse()` as follows:

```
text <- c("A.1    skldjlsfslfjd skdlsdj sljfdkjd.",
'Hello my name is John. Blah blah blah.',
'A.2    skldljsdlkd dkdkd adjklsdk.',
"Hello my last name is Doe. akdjkld slkdlk ldksdl.")

text <- ifelse(!grepl("A.",text) ,gsub("\\..*","",text), text)

text
```

> ```
> "A.1    skldjlsfslfjd skdlsdj sljfdkjd." 
> "Hello my name is John"                  
> "A.2    skldljsdlkd dkdkd adjklsdk."    
> "Hello my last name is Doe"
> ```